# How to sort list items dynamically in jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, listview, sorting

My question is very similar to a number of others I've found on Stack Overflow, but not quite the same.

I'v simple list as below:

```
<div id="preview" style="border: 1px solid #000;">

    <ul>
        <li style="list-style: none; display: none;" id="list1" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1" value="a" />
            <label for="answer1" id="displayAnswer1"></label>
        </li>

        <li style="list-style: none; display: none;" id="list2" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2" value="b" />
            <label for="answer2" id="displayAnswer2"></label>
        </li>

         <li style="list-style: none; display: none;" id="list3" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer3" value="c" />
            <label for="answer3" id="displayAnswer3"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In variable named `'id'`, the value may come in random order,
For eg: first value of id may be 3, then li having `list3` id must come in first position of list view, then id value may be 2, then li having `list2` id must come in second position of list view, then at last id value may be 1, then li having `list1` id must come in third position of list view.

I searched alot but all of them are sorted by alphabetically or other something like that value and they are not solving my problem.

Thanx !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
​var ids = [3, 1, 2];

var items = $("#preview li").remove();
$.each(ids, function(index, id) {
    $(items).filter("li[id='list" + ids[index] + "']")
        .appendTo($("#preview ul"));
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QsxPX/4/).

​